# Oracle Sub-select taking a long time

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, optimization

I have a SQL Query that comprise of two level sub-select. This is taking too much time.

The Query goes like:

```
   select * from DALDBO.V_COUNTRY_DERIV_SUMMARY_XREF
    where calculation_context_key = 130205268077
    and DERIV_POSITION_KEY in 
          (select ctry_risk_derivs_psn_key 
            from DALDBO.V_COUNTRY_DERIV_PSN
            where calculation_context_key = 130111216755 
            --and ctry_risk_derivs_psn_key = 76296412
            and CREDIT_PRODUCT_TYPE = 'SWP OP'
            and CALC_OBLIGOR_COUNTRY_OF_ASSETS in 
                (select ctry_cd 
                 from DALDBO.V_PSN_COUNTRY
                 where calculation_context_key = 130134216755 
                --and ctry_risk_derivs_psn_key = 76296412
                )
           )
```

These tables are huge! Is there any optimizations available?

Comment: Way too little information. What is the schema? What are the existing indexes? What does the query plan look like? What is "huge" in this case? Also, your query isn't complete, it's missing at least one end parenthesis (the one commented out?)

Comment: 1. All these schemas are indexed on a primary key. Like V_COUNTRY_DERIV_SUMMARY_XREF has V_COUNTRY_DERIV_SUMMARY_XREF_key
2. We can ignore this table: DALDBO.V_PSN_COUNTRY. The other two are fairly large
3. I am not sure about query plan.

Comment: why not join? (instead of subselects).  But as Joachim noted, way too little info

Comment: By huge I mean we enter almost a million record in these tables everyday, for past 6-7 months!!!

Comment: @Vivek we cant guess what your primary keys are, so telling us these tables are indexed on the primary key doesn't tell us much. also you table names start `V_` which makes me wonder, are these tables or views (as many places tend to use `v_` for views). do your tables have an index that covers all the columns you're filtering on here and how many rows does each sub select result in)?

Comment: You are right. These are views on top of table which has same name(except V_) and add _KEY for the primary key, which was added by an auto-incrementing generator, while entering data into these tables.

Comment: Anyway appreciate, all your efforts. I guess i'll have to live with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your table or view definitions, indexing, etc. I would start by looking at the sub-selects and ensuring that they are performing optimally.  I would also want to know how many values are being returned by each sub-select as this can impact performance.

How is calculation_context_key used to retrieve rows from V_COUNTRY_DERIV_PSN and V_PSN_COUNTRY?  Is it an optimal execution plan?

How is DERIV_POSITION_KEY and CALC_OBLIGOR_COUNTRY_OF_ASSETS used in V_COUNTRY_DERIV_SUMMARY_XREF to retrieve rows?  Again, look at the explain plan.

Comment: The bottom sub-select returns 10 countries, The one on top of it returns around 3800 rows. And all the keys are indexes to respectable table and used in other tables as foreign key to comply association relation.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, can you write this query using inner joins (and not subselect) ??

```
select  A.* 
from    DALDBO.V_COUNTRY_DERIV_SUMMARY_XREF a, 
    DALDBO.V_COUNTRY_DERIV_PSN b,
    DALDBO.V_PSN_COUNTRY c
where   calculation_context_key = 130205268077
and a.DERIV_POSITION_KEY = b.ctry_risk_derivs_psn_key 
and b.calculation_context_key = 130111216755 
--and   b.ctry_risk_derivs_psn_key = 76296412
and b.CREDIT_PRODUCT_TYPE = 'SWP OP'
and     b.CALC_OBLIGOR_COUNTRY_OF_ASSETS = c.ctry_cd 
and c.calculation_context_key = 130134216755 
--and   c.ctry_risk_derivs_psn_key = 76296412
```

second, best practice says that when you don't query any data from the tables in the subselect you better of using an EXISTS instead of IN. new versions of oracle does that automatically and actually rewrite the whole thing as an inner join.

last, without any knowledge on you data and of what you are trying to do i would suggest you to try and use views as less as you can - if you can query the underling tables it would be best and you will probably see immediate performance improvement.